# Submission button is not working when it's coonnected to MySQL database using flask framework

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

The submission button is not working properly. I'm getting the desired output after submitting the form. Kindly let me know where I'm going wrong. Find the attached .html and .py code below. Also, let me know what's the difference between using "button" tag and "input" tag as buttons in html?

**main.py**

```
mysql=MySQL(app)

@app.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])
def insert():
    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
    if request.form=='POST':
        print(request.form["description"])
    cur.execute("select * from test.task")
    task=cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return render_template("base.html",task=task)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

**base.html**

```
<body>
    <h3>Table</h3>

    {% block body %}
    <div>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description Input" required>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="=Task">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No.</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Date and time</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

            {% for task in task %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{loop.index}}</td>
                <td>{{task.1}}</td>
                <td>{{task.2}}</td>
                <td><a href="Update">Update</a> <a href="Delete">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}



        </table>
    </div>
    {% endblock body %}

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show me errors on backend cosole, when you click submit button on front end

Comment: It's not showing any error. It's because I have redirected the action of the form to the homepage("/"). At the same time after pressing the submit button, it should print "hello" on the console screen of the backend which it's not printing at all. Not getting where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you gived same route value (@app.route("/", ...)) for homepage and insert?

Comment: Right now I'm not inserting anything. I just want the button to work properly and print the desired out (which is ---> print("hello").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this with:

```
if request.form == "POST":
```

with

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Comment: you can mark it as accepted answer if you want.